# Linux, SVN and Dropbox -- Which directory should store my svn repository?

Tags: linux, directory-structure, subversion, dropbox

I'm trying to set up a linux server for a small team of programmers / artists to use as a svn repository. This repository will be restricted to lan usage but will be backed up online using dropbox. *Basically, my idea is to have a backup on the dropbox in case of hard-drive failures or in cases where we need to quickly replace the hardware (simply download the dropbox, initialize the new server.)* I'm new to this whole thing, but I feel like this is necessary for me to set up now before making any more progress on our project.

I think I get what needs to be done for the most part but an issue has come up with regards to where in the file system I should store the repository.

**I'm pretty new to linux stilll which makes this a hard decision for me to make. Where in the linux directory structure I should store a svn repository?** Ideally, this repository should be inside a dropbox synced directory in order to keep a backup of the entire project online.

P.S. Before people suggest alternatives, I'm pretty set on using SVN. At least, for the time being. Windows support is a must for us and things like Git Annex are still a bit shaky on that platform.

Comment: I have used `/srv/svn/username/repos` when I used svn, which has been a long time now. Mercurial works fine on Windows. Use that instead. To be quite frank, Subversion is a piece of crap and best buried in the dustbin of history. Unless you are a large corporation and want to do the corporate control freak thing.

Comment: The problem I have with mercurial is that it's distributed which will be a pain when the repository reaches a large size. We were/are using git for code right now which works amazingly, but we're putting a lot of art assets in (game project) and would like to have some basic means of art version control on a centralized server.

Why is subversion bad exactly? It seems like git sucks for binary files, and git-annex doesn't fully support windows as well as svn. Ideally, I'd like to use one VCS but it's becoming less likely possible with the demands of the project.

Comment: Well, Linus Torvalds did a video on git vs svn/cvs, so check that out. I think it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idLyobOhtO4. At one point he calls Subversion stupid and ugly. I'm not generally a big fan of LT's offensive style, but in this case I agree with him. Also see http://hginit.com/, which has some discussion of svn vs hg if I remember rightly. What kind of repos sizes were you talking about? It's true that mercurial does not support partial or shallow clones, whereas with svn you can at least do a partial checkout.

Comment: Granted, there are cases where svn may be a better choice than distributed VCS, and I've never had to work with large binary files in a version control context, so I'm not familar with that use case. On the other hand, I don't see why svn would be better for large binary files than hg/git. I don't think hg support for large files is stellar (the extension is called `largefiles` I think), but I would check it out in any case. You can also talk to people on #mercurial on Freenode.

Comment: The relevant hginit.com page is http://hginit.com/00.html, where Joel Spolsky does a good job explaining the deficiencies of the centralized model.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two sensible locations to put the "data" for services.

**The distribution default location:**

Usually, the distribution chose a default location for a service data (redhat/centos use `/var/svn`, debian tend to use `/var/lib/svn`). It is much easier and faster to use that location : configuration is already or almost ready, integration with various components is easier (like SELinux file contexts). It does have some limitation. The distribution location is often limited to "single instance" ; your data are stored in various locations, etc.

**The `/srv` hierarchy:**

The Linux [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) states that `/srv` *contains a site-specific data which is served by this system ([link](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM))*. Some administrators like to gather data here, and structure that hierarchy in a way that sensible for them (by environments, by customer...)